# What is the relationship between $I_{n}$ and $I_{n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$I_{n}(\gamma)=\int_{0}^{\gamma}\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^5\right)^n}$$
where $n\in \mathbf{N}$.

What is the relationship between $I_{n}$ and $I_{n+1}$?

Comment: Is there a reason you expect a relationship? What kind of relationship are you hoping to find?

Comment: You definitely get that $I_{n+1}<I_n$ when $\gamma> 0.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use integration by parts
$$
I_{n} = \int_{0}^{\gamma}\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^5\right)^n} = \frac{x}{(1+x^5)^n}\bigg|^\gamma_0 + 5n \int_0^\gamma \frac{x^5}{(1+x^5)^{n+1}}dx =
$$
$$
= \frac{\gamma}{(1+\gamma^5)^n} +5n I_n - 5n I_{n+1}.
$$
Then we have
$$
I_{n+1} = \frac{5n-1}{5n} I_n + \frac{1}{5n} \frac{\gamma}{(1+\gamma^5)^n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could write
$$I_{n+1}(\gamma) = \int_0^\gamma \frac{dx}{(1+x^5)^{n+1}} = \int_0^\gamma \frac{dx}{(1+x^5)^n} - \int_0^\gamma \frac{x^5dx}{(1+x^5)^{n+1}} = I_n(\gamma) -  \int_0^\gamma \frac{x^5dx}{(1+x^5)^{n+1}}$$
and try to reach something in the second integral through integration by parts. I hope this is the kind of relationship you are looking for.